# App crashes at start when using OpenCV 2.3.1 in Qt 4.8.0

Tags: qt, opencv, crash

I tried to control my camera using OpenCV functions. The building progress is fine, however, when I tried to run my program it crashes and Qt only gives the information about the exit code -1073741515. I tried to comment all of the code using OpenCV function and the program seems to be OK. Are the libraries I included the wrong ones?

**opencv.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = opencv
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += F:/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += F:/opencv/build/include/opencv

LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_calib3d231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_contrib231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_core231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_features2d231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_flann231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_gpu231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_highgui231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_imgproc231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_legacy231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_ml231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_objdetect231.dll.a
LIBS += F:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_video231.dll.a
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

Since MainWindow.cpp is long, I will just paste the constructor here and add the rest of them if needed.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cam = NULL;
    frame = NULL;
    timer = new QTimer;
    imag = new QImage();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(readFrame()));
    connect(ui->open,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(openCamara()));
    connect(ui->pic,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(takingPictures()));
    connect(ui->closeCam,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(closeCamara()));
}
```

Comment: You are probably using some pointer without initializing it.

Comment: @karlphillip I init all pointers used by slot functions in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally GET IT WORK! When I try to run the app from Windows Explorer, it complains about lack of **libstdc++-6.dll**. Although there exist on under C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin, its version is incorrect for OpenCV 2.3 (or any other reason?) and will cause an error. I got one from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wtfu/downloads/detail?name=libstdc%2b%2b-6.dll&can=2&q=) and the program runs correctly.